# How to perform a test for trend on an ordinal variable in logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, ordinal-data, trend

I have a dichotomous outcome (gallstones/no gallstones) and an ordinal predictor variable consisting of four classes (body mass index <25(ref.), 25-30, 30-35, 35-45). I want to perform a test for trends using `R`.

When running the `glm` function only the bmi 35-45 is significantly associated with the outcome (gallstones):

```
glm(formula = gallstones ~ bmi, family = binomial, data = m)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.9282  -0.4058  -0.3624  -0.3624   2.3477  

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     -2.6902     0.1476 -18.223  < 2e-16 ***

bmi(25,30]   0.2347     0.2131   1.102   0.2706    
bmi(30,35]   0.6108     0.3291   1.856   0.0635 .  
bmi(35,45]   2.0712     0.4915   4.214 2.51e-05 ***
```

To examine if there is a dose-response relationship with a linear trend with rising bmi I perform the analysis of variance with the chi-square test:

```
anova(inc_test_3, test="Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: binomial, link: logit

Response: gallstones

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


          Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)   
NULL                      1489     810.05            
bmi       3   15.892      1486     794.16 0.001193 **
```

There is a significant difference between the obtained estimates from the ordinal bmi predictor.

Is this the correct way to test for a trend on an ordinal variable?

Comment: In your analysis of deviance you haven't tested for trend at all, but simply compared the null model with one having a four-level categorical predictor. [Orthogonal polynomial coding](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm#ORTHOGONAL) is useful for examining trends, & in fact is the default when you tell R the predictor is ordinal (see `?ordered`).

Comment: Thank you - I was not aware of the ordered function in R. However, what if we concider the variable to be a factor? I am not sure if it is all right to assume that the jumps in this BMI variable are completely ordinal. I have created the BMI variable with the default cut function in R.

Comment: (1) Not sure what you mean by "consider the variable to be a factor". Orthogonal polynomial coding doesn't produce a substantively different model from e.g. reference level coding. (2) It doesn't seem at all likely that the chance of having a gallstone jumps at BMIs of 25, 30, 35, & 45, or that it's constant between those BMIs. See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68834/). If you have BMI then use it as a predictor rather than cutting it, allowing for curvilinearity with polynomials or (probably better) splines.

Comment: Sorry for jumping to conclusions to soon:) What i mean is the scenario where the continuous variable has no association on the outcome but I assume it to have an association based on previous analyses. Therefore, I would like to cut the variable into a multi-class categorical variable. Would that be totally wrong?

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand the "therefore". Are you saying that when you treated the predictor as having a *linear* relationship to the response (on the logit scale) you found no (or only a weak) association, & you therefore binned the predictor to allow for a curvilinear relationship? If so, that's not *totally* wrong, but not a very good way of modelling it - read the post I linked to.

Comment: @Scortchi The orthogonal polynomial coding worked perfect! You want to post it as an answer so i can rate it?

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, and expanding over  
@Scortchi - Reinstate Monica's comments below the post, the solution is to force `R` to recognise that `bmi` is an ordered factor variable. This can be done by calling the `ordered` function, thus the correct `R` code would be:

```
m$ordered_bmi <- ordered(bmi)
glm(formula = gallstones ~ ordered_bmi, family = binomial, data = m)
```

Ensure that the order is the one you have in mind by checking the levels of `odrederd_bmi`. If that doesn't happen, feed in the order of the factors yourself by specifying the `levels` option, e.g.

```
m$ordered_bmi <- ordered(bmi, levels = c("<25", "25-30", "30-35", "35-45"))
```